# Existence of Banach Limits

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Just want to check everything is good.

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Define $T: l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \to l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ by $$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_2,x_3,x_4,...),$$ $$M=\{x-Tx:x \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\},$$ and $e=(1,1,1,...)$. Then

$(a)$ $T \in \mathcal{L}(l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$ ($T$ is both continuous and linear) and $\Vert T \Vert = 1$;

$(b)$ $M \leq l_{\infty}$ and $d(e,M)=1$;

$(c)$ There exists $f \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})'$ such that

$(1)$ $\Vert f \Vert = 1$,

$(2)$ for each $x \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ we have $f(x)=f(T(x))$ and

$(3)$ for each $(x_n) \in c(\mathbb{R})$ we have $f((x_n))=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$,

$(4)$ for each $(x_n) \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n \geq 0$, we have $f((x_n)) \geq 0$.

$\textbf{Proof}:$ It's easy to check $T \in \mathcal{L}(l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $M \leq l_{\infty}$. Since $0_{l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} \in M$, $d(e,M) \leq 1$. Let $x=(x_n) \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. If for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n-x_{n+1} \leq 0$, then $$1 \leq \vert 1-(x_n-x_{n+1}) \vert \leq \Vert e-(x-T(x)) \Vert;$$ if on the other hand for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n-x_{n+1} \geq 0$, that is, $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$ exists, so that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n-x_{n+1}=0$ and we have $$1 \leq \Vert e-(x-T(x)) \Vert.$$ We conclude $d(e,M) \geq 1$, and in fact, $d(e,M)=1$. By (a certain consequence of) the Hahn-Banach Theorem, we can find $f \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})'$ such that $\Vert f \Vert = 1$, $f(e)=1$ and for each $x \in M$, $f(x)=0$, that is, for each $x \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, $$f(x)-f(T(x))=f(x-T(x))=0.$$ Suppose now $x = (x_n) \in c_0(\mathbb{R})$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$T^{n}(x)-x=[T^{n}(x)-T^{n-1}(x)]+...+[T(x)-x] \in M,$$ so that $f(x)=f(T^{n}(x))$; then if $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $m \in \mathbb{N}_{>n}$ implies $\vert x_m \vert < \epsilon$ we have $$\vert f(x) \vert = \vert f(T^n(x)) \vert \leq \Vert T^n(x) \Vert < \epsilon,$$ and therefore $x \in \ker f$, that is, $$f(x)=0=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n.$$ It follows that if $x=(x_n) \in c(\mathbb{R})$, we have $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$. Finally, suppose there exists $x = (x_n) \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n \geq 0$ and $f(x)<0$. Define $\overline{x} = x / \Vert x \Vert$. Then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$0 \leq \overline{x}_n \leq 1 \ \text{and} \ f(\overline{x})<0$$ and therefore $$\Vert e-\overline{x} \Vert \leq 1 \ \text{and} \ f(e-\overline{x})=1-f(\overline{x})>1,$$ which is absurd since $\Vert f \Vert = 1$.

Comment: what is your question

Comment: Is everything correct? Comments? As I said, just wanted to check everything is good.

Comment: Yes, everything seems to be correct. As far as comments go, it was quite clear, but I did not know what $c(\mathbb R)$ stands for.

Comment: @zugg $c(\Bbb R)$ probably means sequences that have a limit (as if they were "eventually constant", hence the name), just as $c_0(\Bbb R)$ are sequences that tend to $0$. Bom trabalho, Bruno!

Comment: @user1952009 What's wrong with the readability?

Comment: @IrregularUser : at first he didn't write what he wanted, and this is only formulas, nowhere he explained what are the concepts / the intuition he is using.

Comment: @user1952009 What do you mean? I've checked the edit history and the first form of this is very close to the current form... and what do you mean that it's "only formulas"? He explains everywhere what is happening.

Comment: @IrregularUser : ok so I guess we don't agree. in particular, that this operator which for any $x \in c$ yields $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ can be extended to any $x \in l^\infty$ with the Hahn-Banach theorem is quite obscure (it is exactly the case where we need the axiom of choice) and I don't see any comment of that, whereas I'm quite sure this is why "he is not sure about what he wrote".

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not trying to cause an argument, I just stumbled upon this question and really didn't understand why you thought that his post wasn't easily readable. But it seems that your definition of "easily readable" is different than what I expected. So I guess that you mean that you don't feel that he has clarified everything in his proof to a standard that you feel is acceptable?

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not completely sure this is what is troubling you, but I'm using the following corolary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem: If $V$ is a normed space , $U \leq V$ and $x \in V-U$, then there exists $f \in V'$ such that $\Vert f \Vert = 1/d(x,U)$, $f(x)=1$ and $f(U)=\{0\}$.